# How can I print the current working directory in a Jenkinsfile using powereshell

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've tried this

```
powershell( returnStdout: true, script: 'Get-Location' )
```

but all I get in the logs is a blank line, worth stating commands like `Write-Output` work.

Comment: Without the `Jenkinsfile` context, this appears more of a powershell/Windows root cause than Jenkins DSL.

Answer (score 0):

Since this syntax returns the output stream, i.e. stream 1 of Powershell output without printing it to the console, you need to store the stdout in a variable and print it explicitly in the Jenkinsfile.

```
currentDir = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: 'Get-Location')
println(currentDir)
```

See [Microsoft PowerShell Support for Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/07/26/powershell-pipeline/).